# Swift Firebase query taking up to a minute

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Ok so I have a Swift app that's loading in this Firebase db into a tableview. The problem is that it can take up to an entire minute to get the Firebase response and load in the data. This happens regardless of the internet connection. Am I doing something wrong here, there's only 7 of those items in the database so I can't see it being an issue with the database being too large. I should also note that it strangly takes at least a minute just to load the Realtime Database through the Firebase console on the browser.

Any idea what's going wrong here? Below is the code where I'm querying the db, and a snapshot of the content I'm loading in the Firebase console.

Oh and I'm using a free Firebase account, but I didn't see any restrictions on speed in the pricing options so I don't think that's the problem.

```
  private func loadItems(){

    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    ref.child("DonationItem").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let values = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {

            for (key,_) in values{

                let donationItem: NSObject = values[key] as! NSObject

                let myTitle: String! = donationItem.value(forKey: "title") as? String
                let myItemID: String! = donationItem.value(forKey: "itemID") as? String

                let myPhotoString = donationItem.value(forKey: "image") as? String
                let decodedData = NSData(base64Encoded: myPhotoString!)
                let myImage = UIImage(data: decodedData as! Data)

                let myDescription = donationItem.value(forKey: "description") as? String
                let myDate = donationItem.value(forKey: "expiration") as? String
                let myLatitude = donationItem.value(forKey: "latitude") as? Double
                let myLongitude = donationItem.value(forKey: "longitude") as? Double
                let myCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: myLatitude!, longitude: myLongitude!)
                let myUserID = donationItem.value(forKey: "userID") as? String
                let myAddress = donationItem.value(forKey: "address") as? String


                var  donated: Bool
                if let donatedInt = donationItem.value(forKey: "donated") as? Int {
                    donated = Bool(donatedInt as NSNumber)
                } else {
                    donated = true
                }

                let donation1 = DonatedItem(myTitle, myImage!, donated, myDescription!, myDate!, myCoordinates, myUserID!, myItemID!, myAddress!)
                self.addItem(item: donation1!)

                }
        }


    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

Here's the Firebase console.

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is the long and lat determined, and is this done before the query is executed? It may not be the query that is problem.

**Edit:**

The encoded image size was the problem to this question in the end. Images can become quite large and slow down response times in a query if they are hard-coded image urls. Watch out for the ways in which you retrieve images.

The better way would be to store images in Firebase Storage and put a reference to it in the DB, as @riper wrote in a comment to this answer.

Comment: I'm actually just hard coding those two values right now as that part of the app is not developed yet -- So I don't believe there's any heavy  computation that's done before the query.

Comment: Have you tried running the query without decoding the image? Put a placeholder image inside the project and load that as a test for now. I can't see any obvious signs of why it may be slowed down, especially with hard-coded values.

Comment: Yeah Doesn't seem to make a difference. Although using a stopwatch it's loading in about 16 secs now (with and without the decoding). I timed how long it takes to load in the web console and it took about 20 secs. Is this just normal for it to take this long?

Comment: So I've found the problem. The encoded image string was so huge it caused the json file to be like 20mb. You're answer put me on the right track so I'll award you with the answer as thanks

Comment: You might wanna store those images in Firebase Storage and just put a reference to it in the realtime db. AFAIK the recommendation is to store up to 10MB in realtime db. On top of that it's much cheaper storing it in Storage if you have a lot of those.

Comment: Hi Brandon. Can you edit out the answer to be a bit more *definitive*? It might help someone who sees this in the future. It'll be easier for them to see it in the answer itself instead of reading through all the comments. Cheers! :)